# Jmeter Query related to multiple threads

Tags: jmeter

I need to run 10 POST request in one thread which will give 10 different responses value and then using those 10 different response value, I need to run 10 GET request in different thread.
How to do it?

I have used JSON extractor and then beanshell assertion for POST request  and then used those assertion value in GET request , but when I run 10 GET request, all request pick up the same response value of POST instead of different values

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need to pass the values between threads (no matter if they're in the same [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) or not) you need to convert JMeter Variable holding the value you want to pass into a JMeter Property
2. JMeter properties are **global** for the whole JVM process so if you use the same property name - the subsequent thread will overwrite the value. So if you need to pass 10 different values you need to:

   - make sure to add a prefix or postfix from 0 to 10 which will help you to distinguish the value, for example you can use [__counter() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) for this
   - make sure to add a prefix or postfix which will return the number of the current thread so each virtual user would have its own property, you can use [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) for this

   More information: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)
3. And last but not the least [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating.